# Need Clarification: Sample Means in LLN and Distribution in CLT

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm seeking clarity on a point of confusion I have with the Law of Large Numbers (LLN) and the Central Limit Theorem (CLT), specifically regarding the behavior of sample means.

As I understand it, the LLN states that the sample mean will converge to the population mean as the sample size increases. This convergence, as I interpret it, suggests that the sample mean should converge exactly to the population mean for a large sample size. However, the CLT posits that the distribution of these sample means approaches a normal distribution for large sample sizes. My confusion arises from this apparent contradiction: if each sample mean converges exactly to the population mean, why would there be a distribution of sample means as indicated by the CLT?

Comment: If $a_n \to 0$ then $\sqrt n a_n$ can converge to a non-zero number right?

Comment: Your "the sample mean should converge *exactly* to the population mean" can lead to confusion over *exactly*.  The limit of the sample means (in probability and almost surely) will be the population mean - this is the LLN - but there is no reason to expect any particular sample mean to be equal to the population mean, particularly when sampling from a continuous distribution.   The CLT can tell you about the limiting distribution of the sample mean after suitable relocation and rescaling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Law of Large Number**

The sample mean converges to the population mean:

$$
\exists N \phantom{x} | \phantom{x}n>N\implies\|\hat{\mu}_{n}-\mu\| < \epsilon \phantom{x}\forall \phantom{x}\epsilon > 0 
$$

LLN **does not** say that each sample mean will be equal to the population mean, it states that the sample means get arbitrarily close to the population mean as the sample size increases.

**Central Limit Theorem**

The distribution of sample means approaches a normal distribution with the following mean and variance:

$$
\hat{\mu}_{n}\to\mathcal{N}\left(\mu,\frac{\sigma^{2}}{n}\right)
$$

Notice that, as $n$ increases, the variance diminishes. Very small variance means the sample means are very close to the mean.

Comment: @beginner: I used to have the same confusion but someone told me to think of it like this: The CLT only holds when you scale by $\sqrt{n}$ so the actual CLT statement is $\sqrt{n}(\hat{u}_{n} - \mu) \rightarrow N(0,\sigma^2)$. The $n$ needs to be on the left side in order to keep the distribution from becoming degenerate.